# How to change texture file names of imported GLTF file when exporting

Tags: edit-mode

I have a 3D object with parts of it a particular color and I edited the main texture file to change the color (using Paint Shop Pro tool).

Color change works well and I can IMPORT the .glTF file and see that it is what I want. Then I EXPORT as an extended glTF to a new folder.

Problem is that although I called the model a different name the texture file names are exported the same as the other one.

Is it possible to export textures with different filenames for the imported texture files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.glTF file imported to Blender has textures *packed*.

---

You have to click **Unpack** icon in properties panel (accessible when image node selected in Side panel <kbd>N</kbd>) ... Blender *Creates texture folder* (directory) where textures will be stored.

[image]

[image]

Or you can *Unpack All* see [Manuall](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html).

[image]

Than you can navigate to this directory and rename your texture files.

---

Note: ... but then you have to rename the path to those textures in blender as well.
I don't think there is an option to batch rename via blender's exporter.

Comment: Thanks I too wondered if the textures were packed but also noticed that if the textures are not in the same folder as the .glTF files they don't display when imported (in FS2020 the texture files must be in a separate folder named textures. Unfortunately I got lost trying to follow your instructions. I referred to my Blender for Dummies to find out how to get the Properties and then could not understand what was displayed on screen. I also tried just pressing N and only got the Transform menu. I also searched for UNPACK in the manual and didn't find anything.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html ... If you are still lost I will add some screenshots ... I refered to individually unpack - switch to shader layout, select texture node and when hovering mouse still above shader window press N to bring up side panel with properties.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of looking in the (official) Blender manual thinking that Blender for Dummies (over 600 pages) would include most if not all. I will give that a try later.

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots